# CSS rotate3d doesn't seem to follow a consistent rule?

Tags: css, animation, rotation

I'm recently following this [guide](https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/3d-transform-functions) to learn about 3D rotations and figuring out the direction of rotation for each axis (cw or ccw).

My main question:
It appears RotateX and RotateZ follows the left hand rule but RotateY follows the right hand rule? (The same goes for rotate3d.)

A follow up question:
For the spinning 3D cube [example](https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/cube), I don't understand why all the for the animation to work, the transform rotation degrees needs to have their signs flipped. (Also it seems the translateZ(-100px) is optional from my testing).

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Are you suggesting I should remove the follow-up question?

Comment: Yes............